# Why does this Access report edit the underlying query?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a bizzare issue with an Access report. Namely, when the report is used it edits the code of its source query, and breaks the query. The underlying query starts as:

```
select b.Cont_staff, b.tot_success, c.tot_fail
from
(select Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_success
from
    (SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff
    FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
    where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Successful')
group by Cont_staff) as b
left join 
(select Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_fail
from
    (SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff
    FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
    where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Unsuccessful') 
group by Cont_staff) as c
on b.cont_staff = c.cont_staff
```

The report is very simple, one field for each of `Cont_staff`, `tot_success`, and `tot_fail` in the report Detail. There are static labels in the report Header.

The query runs correctly when first created, and the report run correctly the first time it is opened. But if you close the report and re-open it, it changes the query code to this:

```
SELECT b.Cont_staff, b.tot_success, c.tot_fail
FROM 
    (SELECT Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) AS tot_success 
    FROM 
    [SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff FROM dbo_UIH_contacts where dbo_UIH_contacts].[Cont_result = 'Successful'] 
    AS [%$##@_Alias] 
GROUP BY Cont_staff)  AS b 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) AS tot_fail 
    FROM 
    [SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff FROM dbo_UIH_contacts where dbo_UIH_contacts].[Cont_result = 'Unsuccessful'] 
    AS [%$##@_Alias] 
GROUP BY Cont_staff)  AS c 
ON b.cont_staff = c.cont_staff
```

In Access it's one text string with no line breaks. The changed part is where it brackets sub-selects and inserts `[%$##@_Alias]`.

**Update**

The problem does not seem to be with the report specifically, the same thing happens when set a form to use the query.

Comment: *it changes the query code to this* ... Where does query change? Are you retrieving this SQL from a recordsource in report design? If a saved query changes now that is very interesting given it is a cached, compiled object to best execution plan by engine!

Answer (score 0):

Try using aliases for the innermost queries.

```
select b.Cont_staff, b.tot_success, c.tot_fail
from (select Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_success
      from (SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff
            FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
            where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Successful') AS Q1
      group by Cont_staff) as b
left join 
     (select Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_fail
      from (SELECT Cont_date, Cont_result, Cont_staff
            FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
            where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Unsuccessful') AS Q2 
      group by Cont_staff) as c
on b.cont_staff = c.cont_staff;
```

Actually, not sure you even need the innermost queries; try:

```
select b.Cont_staff, b.tot_success, c.tot_fail
from (select Cont_staff, count(*) as tot_success
      FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
      where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Successful'
      group by Cont_staff) as b
left join 
     (select Cont_staff, count(*) as tot_fail FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
      where dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result = 'Unsuccessful')
      group by Cont_staff) as c
on b.cont_staff = c.cont_staff;
```

Or maybe a crosstab:

```
TRANSFORM Count(ContDate) AS CountOfContDate
SELECT Cont_Staff
FROM dbo_UIH_contacts
GROUP BY Cont_Staff
PIVOT Cont_result IN ("Successful", "Unsuccessful");
```

Comment: I had done aliases on the innermost queries originally and the posted version is the second draft with those aliases removed to try to clean it up. The innermost queries are there because I'm going to be sub-setting by date range (I was about the add that code when it broke), otherwise you'd be right about them being unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

While I did not determine the exact cause of the code-overwriting, the problem does not occur if I split the query into two Access query objects. So it seems the Access cannot handle this kind of three-level query.

First create this query (which has the date filtering code that was the next step for the query in the question). Let's call it `qry_Conts_by_dt`:

```
SELECT 
    dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_key
    , dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_date
    , dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_result
    , dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_staff
FROM dbo_UIH_contacts 
WHERE 
    (((dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_date)>=[Forms]![frm_Cont_status_by_coord]![bx_start_dt] 
    And (dbo_UIH_contacts.Cont_date)<=[Forms]![frm_Cont_status_by_coord]![bx_end_dt])
;
```

Then reference the first query:

```
SELECT b.Cont_staff, b.tot_success, c.tot_fail
FROM 
    (SELECT Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_success
    FROM  qry_Conts_by_dt
    WHERE qry_Conts_by_dt.Cont_result = 'Successful'
    GROUP BY Cont_staff)  AS b 
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT Cont_staff, count(Cont_staff) as tot_fail
    FROM  qry_Conts_by_dt
    WHERE qry_Conts_by_dt.Cont_result = 'Unsuccessful' 
    GROUP BY Cont_staff)  AS c ON b.cont_staff = c.cont_staff;
```

And use the second query as the Record Source for the report (or form for that matter).